# Passing an array type argument for new command

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, loops, foreach

I've looked around and can't seem to find anywhere, but I was wondering if there is somewhere you can do something like the following:

```
\newcommand{\loopy}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in #1 {
            \foreach \y in \x {
                \node at (\y_1,\y_2);
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\loopy{{{1,2},{2,3}}}
```

Then the 'loopy' command would go through and plot nodes at (1,2) and (2,3). I'm not sure this is even possible or how you would go about doing it?

Additionally, would there be a way to see the number of elements within a number? So say I pass in

```
\loopy{{{1,2,3},{2,3}}}
```

Is there a way to know that the first set has 3 elements and the second set has 2?

**Edit** (Adding more description)

The above example was to simplistic, so I'll make a more 'complex' example to show kinda what I'm trying to do:

```
\newcommand{\loopy}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in #1 {
            \if \x has 2 elements {
                \foreach \y in \x {
                    \node at (\y_1,\y_2);
                }
            }
            \else if \x has 3 elements {
                \foreach \y in \x {
                    \node at (\y_1,\y_2) {\y_3};
                }
            }
            \else if \x has 4 elements {
                \foreach \y in \x {
                    \node at (\y_1,\y_2);
                    \node at (\y_3,\y_4);
                }
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\loopy{{{1,2},{1,2,3},{2,3,4,5}}}
```

Comment: `\newcommand{\loopy}[1]{\tikz{\foreach \x in #1 {\node[draw] at (\x){};}}}` is sufficient. For the counting, as far as I know, no. You have to touch all elements to count the elements.

Comment: What do you mean by touch?

Also, I wanted to access each element individually. The example above was just a torn down version hence why I asked the supplementary question. I'll likely be passing 3-4 element sets and would need to know each item within each set individually. (I'll update the question to better explain the question)

Comment: I mean there is no inherent attribute of the array that holds the element number. You need to explicitly go through the elements(count) to get the number of elements. That means you have to "touch" every element at least once to count and possibly more if you want to switch based on the no of elements. It's not difficult but just extra programming steps.\

Comment: And that's the part I don't understand. How do you explicitly go through each element? Do I just keep making nested foreach loops then?

Comment: Ok, basically I had to go through a foreach loop within foreach loop to get it done. Thanks for the help though =)

Comment: @AramPapazian if this is solved, would you like to write a self-answer so it can be useful to future visitors?

Comment: @AramPapazian Should the question be closed (self-answer is still missing)? Or do you like to write a self-answer 3.5 years later?

Comment: I didn't realize this was still open. Sorry. Yeah it should definitely be closed.

Answer (score 2):

The question seems a bit ill-defined, but one can indeed parse a general list in a nested way, and do different things based on the list length of each successive rank-1 list.  Here

```
\loopy{1,2: 2,3,7: 2,4,4,5}
```

will place a `2` at location (1,2), since it was a 2-element list.
It will place a `3_7` at location (2,3), since `7` was the third element of the list starting with the coordinates (2,3).
Finally, it will place a `4_1` and `4_2` at (2,4) and (4,5) since the 4 element list began with `2,4` and concluded with `4,5`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,tikz}
\newcommand{\loopy}[1]{%
  \setsepchar{:/,}%
  \readlist\mylist{#1}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreachitem\x\in\mylist[]{%
          \ifnum\listlen\mylist[\xcnt]=2\relax
            \node at (\mylist[\xcnt,1],\mylist[\xcnt,2]){$2$};
          \else
            \ifnum\listlen\mylist[\xcnt]=3\relax
              \node at (\mylist[\xcnt,1],\mylist[\xcnt,2]){$3_{\mylist[\xcnt,3]}$};
            \else
              \ifnum\listlen\mylist[\xcnt]=4\relax
                \node at (\mylist[\xcnt,1],\mylist[\xcnt,2]){$4_1$};
                \node at (\mylist[\xcnt,3],\mylist[\xcnt,2]){$4_2$};
              \fi
            \fi
          \fi
        }
   \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\loopy{1,2: 2,3,7: 2,4,4,5}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is still undocumented but there is a math function `dim` for counting stuff inside a comma separated array. So you can use that to branch of via `\ifnum`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath,pgffor}
\def\loopy#1{%
  \foreach\x in#1{%
    \pgfmathdim{\x}\edef\tmp{\noindent There are \pgfmathresult{} elements.\par}\tmp%
  }
}
\begin{document}
\loopy{{{1,2},{1,2,3},{2,3,4,5}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Still not in the documentation, I think, but it is [documented](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35949/9335) on TeX.SX ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one "low level" solution.

I define `\def\switch#1,#2,#3,#4,#5;{...}` which is called with something like `\switch1,2,3,,,,;`, which set the parameter `#4` to be empty (and `#5` is `,,`). So we can check that there are only 3 parameters by `\ifx,#4,<executed when #4 is empty>\else...\fi`.

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\def\switch#1,#2,#3,#4,#5;{
  \ifx,#2,\node[green] at (#1,1) {one variable : #1};\else
  \ifx,#3,\node[red] at (#1,#2) {two variables: #1,#2};\else
  \ifx,#4,\node[blue] at (#2,#3) {three variables: #1,#2,#3};\else
          \draw[orange] (#1,#2) -- node[sloped, above]{four variables:#1,#2,#3,#4} (#3,#4);
  \fi\fi\fi
}
\newcommand*{\loopy}[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {#1} {
      \expandafter\switch\x,,,,;
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \loopy{{1},{1,2},{1,2,3},{-1,3,4,5}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you can use `\ifcase`

Comment: @percusse how can I use `\ifcase` to detect the first empty argument ?

Comment: Oh yes you are doing the reverse indeed then nevermind.