# Length of a list as pgfmath-function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I read [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35947/46023) but I would like to have a pgfmath-function that gives the length of a list like `\def\mylist{1,2,3,5,7}`, because I need the value for some later calculations.

The following does not work correctly.

I get an output:  `112357` 
It should be:  `5`

What do I have to do?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Len}{1}{%
\begingroup
\def\templist{#1}
\foreach[count=\mycount] \i in \templist {   \xdef\Len{\mycount}  }%
\Len%
\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\def\mylist{1,2,3,5,7}
\pgfmathparse{Len(\mylist)}\pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that PGF arrays should have an additional set of braces: with

```
\def\myarray{{1,2,3}}
\pgfmathparse{dim{\myarray}}
```

you get 3 stored in `\pgfmathresult`.

You can access the *n*-th item by

```
\pgfmathparse{\myarray[n]}
```

which stores in `\pgfmathresult` the *n*-th item. Remember that indexing starts at 0.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\newcommand{\myarray}{{640,231,100,91,1003}}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathparse{dim{\myarray}}\pgfmathresult: should be 5

\pgfmathparse{\myarray[4]}\pgfmathresult: should be 1003

\pgfmathparse{dim({640,231,100,91,1003})}\pgfmathresult: should be 5

\pgfmathparse{dim{{640,231,100,91,1003}}}\pgfmathresult: should be 5

\end{document}
```

You see that `dim(...)` or `dim{...}` are equivalent, but the braces around the array are needed anyway.

[image]

Comment: My fault: I do ne look after sequences of the kind 1,2,...,n. The sequence could be whatever...

Comment: And I do not know, what dim calcs, e.g. `\pgfmathparse{dim(200,1,3)}\pgfmathresult` gives 5, but I need 3.

Comment: @cis I added a full example.